# Which area of memory is allocated to managed entity objects in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

In JPA, there is a persistence context which keeps all the entity objects which are in managed state so that if request for same object comes again, there is no need to fetch it from database and return it from the persistence context itself. 
I was curious about in which memory region, this persistence context gets memory ? Is it inside JVM only or where ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a persistence provider that would keep it outside of the Java heap, but that would require native code and the advantages would be questionable.

The persistence providers are normal Java code, so the objects it creates are in the Java heap.

Comment: I have read that the persistence context in jpa is a type of cache(like 1st level cache in hibernate). So is this cache actually residing in the heap memory ? And is this region of heap different from that in which normal objects of Java (created by 'new' keyword) resides ? Please clarify.

Comment: Or does it mean that Entity Manger object created by the persistence provider is a very large object which holds all the managed entity objects inside it ? Please clarify.

Comment: There's the 1st level cache inside the persistence context and there's nothing magical about it. It's just regular Java code written by a regular Joe. The 2nd level cache can be implemented in many ways, whether a Java solution such as `EHCache`, or a non-Java solution like `memcached` running either on the same machine or preferably on its own server(s).